# AutoMapper Get the value of the destination field

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I have

```
public class UserResource
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Salt { get; set; }
   public string Hash { get; set; }
}
```

in the mapping configuration,

```
CreateMap<UserResource, User>()
.ForMember(u => u.SaltPassword, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => PasswordHasher.GenerateSalt()))
.ForMember(u => u.HashPasword, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => PasswordHasher.HashPassword(m.Password,"u.SaltPassword")));
```

The method PasswordHasher.HashPassword("Password","SaltPassword") takes two parameters:

1. userPassword
2. SaltPassword

I want to get `u.SaltPassword` into the `HashPassword("Password", "u.SaltPassword")` method.

Answer (score 0):

Because these properties depend on one another, I think the AfterMap event is more suited. The [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions).